# Change multiple value labels using tidyverse syntax?

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-labelled

The `labelled` package provides this functionality to modify value labels for multiple variables in one go:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:3, v2 = c(2, 3, 1), v3 = 3:1)
val_labels(df[, c("v1", "v3")]) <- c(YES = 1, MAYBE = 2, NO = 3)
val_labels(df)
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in tidyverse syntax:

Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%
mutate(across(V1:V2), ~val_labels(.x)<-c(YES = 1, MAYBE = 2, NO = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to assign and then return the column (`.x`).  In addition, when there are more than one expression, wrap it inside the `{}`

```
library(dplyr)
library(labelled)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(v1:v2, ~ 
       {
       val_labels(.x) <- c(YES = 1, MAYBE = 2, NO = 3)
       .x
     }))
```

-output

```
> val_labels(df)
$v1
  YES MAYBE    NO 
    1     2     3 

$v2
  YES MAYBE    NO 
    1     2     3 

$v3
NULL
```

Comment: This is a better answer because it keeps any variable labels intact. The proposed solution below deletes any variable labels.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `haven`'s labelled class directly, alternatively check out the `labelled` package's functions made for the `dplyr` syntax, e.g. `add_value_labels`.

```r
df <-
  df |>
  mutate(across(v1:v2,
                ~ haven::labelled(.,
                                  labels = c(YES   = 1,
                                             MAYBE = 2,
                                             NO    = 3)
                                  )
                )
         )

labelled::val_labels(df)
```

**Output:**

```r
$v1
  YES MAYBE    NO 
    1     2     3 

$v2
  YES MAYBE    NO 
    1     2     3 

$v3
NULL
```

**A side note:** Unless you have a very specific reason for using the `labelled`-package I'd suggest that you keep the usage to a minimum and coerce into `factors`, especially in the case of value labels. I've learned the hard way that the `labelled`-package (and `sjlabelled` for that matter) will often let you do things that seems smart on the outset but isn't *in the long run*.

> A labelled vector is a common data structure in other statistical environments, allowing you to assign text labels to specific values. (...) **This class provides few methods, as I expect you'll coerce to a standard R class (e.g. a factor()) soon after importing.**

https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/labelled.html
(My emphasis)

Comment: I'm just dropping this comment here for anyone else, as I've encountered this use case several times. Before I ever get to analyzing data, I'm often survey data from Qualtrics or other SPSS style survey data files. Right now, in my current file, the values and value labels on a bunch of likert items are all buggered up. Instead of 1 being Strongly agree, 6 is strongly agree, going to 11, strongly disagree.

Functions like this are useful in batch processing these kinds of problems all at once.